# Finding and storing combinations

Tags: java, c++, arrays, permutation, combinations

I have a n-digit number composed of 1's only. I want to replace 1's with 0's in all possible combinations and store the combinations in an array.
How do I find all combinations?
I was thinking of starting with one zero and then increasing the number if zeroes that will replace 1's.
If there are 2 zeroes, for example, then i will keep the position of one zero fixed and move the other, till it reaches the end then i'd do the same for the other zero. But then i'll have to root out the repeated combinations.
Basically, this is getting complicated. I want to know a better way to find combinations!

Comment: print number from 0 to 2^(n) in binary that is your answer in n digits

Answer (score 3):

You are simply trying to generate `n-digit binary numbers`. It means that you can generate `2^n` different numbers. So here you go:

- Firstly, calculate `2^n`.
- Implement a loop, starting from `0` and ending at `2^n`.
- For every loop variable, take the variable as a decimal and convert
  it to binary and append some leading zeros (if necessary) to make it
  length of n.
- Add the binary to your permutations array.

Comment: Can't I append leading ones to make it of length n if required?